# function calling in c++

Tags: c++, function, call

Where Im mistaking. It says that number variable is not initialized.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ispisi_broj(int a) {

    cout << " Input number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int number; 
    ispisi_broj(number);
```

Comment: You must pass `number` by reference, so declare `a` as `int& a`.

Comment: `ispisi_broj(number);` makes a copy of the variable `number`.  Which is not initialized.

Comment: Recommendation: Rather than passing in parameter `a`, read into a local variable and return it. Eg `int ispisi_broj() { int a; /* blah blah blah */ return a; }` and then `int number; = ispisi_broj();`.

Comment: Question goes like this:

Comment: @SlavoljubRadosavljevic you may still [edit] this question.

Comment: Correction to above: `int number; = ispisi_broj();` should be `int number = ispisi_broj();`

Comment: Create function ispisi_broj(int a) which takes number a of int type as a parameter , and writes it. Then call it from main program. Use cin operator

Comment: *takes number a of int type as a parameter , and writes it.* reads to me as `ispisi_broj` should merely print `a`, not read the value in from the user. Reading in the value should be done elsewhere, probably in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
int ispisi_broj(int a) {

    cout << " Input number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

the value of the parameter a is not used because it is at once reassigned in this statement

```
cin >> a;
```

So the function declaration does not make a great sense.

Also the return type `int` of the function also does not make a sense.

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ispisi_broj( int &a ) 
{
    cout << " Input number: ";
    cin >> a;
}

int main() 
{
    int number; 

    ispisi_broj(number);

    cout << " Input number: ";
    cout << a << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

That is if you want to change the variable `number` declared in main within the function `ispisi_broj` then you need to pass it to the function by reference.